# Java vs MySQL: float type difference

Tags: java, mysql, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

I'm using float numbers in java, printing them and storing them in a MySQL float column. The result is that the java printing shows as follows
x=260.1201   y=260.12

It's ok, because x=y+0.0001
When i try to store those values in tow float column on MySQL the values i can read inside it are
x=260.12    y=260.12

Why that difference? Aren't java's float and MySQL's float the same thing?

Just another question: at which larger value i can expect to work correctly with java float for a precision of 0.0001?

Answer (score 3):

You're pushing the limits of 32-bit IEEE 754 [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) floating point precision.  It has about 24 bits of precision. The usual rule of thumb is that the smallest incremental value available is about 1 / 10**7 of the value of the number you're incrementing.

261.1200 and 261.1201 are, to the level of precision stored in a `FLOAT`, the same value. This SQL Fiddle demonstrates that fact.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a521/2/0

All `float` and `double` numbers are approximations.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-float.html

http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/91float/

It's never a surprise when two float values aren't `==` equal to each other even if you thought they should be. It's always a surprise when they are.

Comment: Yeah, i'm pushing them because i'm facing numbers there was not supposed to be included in the project. I still don't need a total precision, but i'd like to know in advance how the problem can be severe... Anyway, the standard is the same, i really can't understand that difference. You say it's normal, but What's the reason?

Comment: See my edit, and this sqlfiddle.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a521/2/0  For an explanation of what's going on here, read the princeton reference I cited.

Comment: Offers no solution whatsoever to have sql and java floating points stored in the same way

Answer (score 2):

I know it is very old discussion thread but today I solved same problem and thinking to share with you all.

In database side one of the column is float and I was sending float data using

```
call = (CallableStatement)this.getStatement();
call.setFloat(floatData)
```

But when I try to save some float value then correct data does NOT saved in database and some how it got converted into different decimal value.

SOLUTION:

Then I convert floatData into dobule value and called

```
call.setDouble(doubledata)
```

even though in database column is float type.

Now it is working fine.